# Edit firebase object from dom-repeat in Dialog

Tags: firebase, polymer-1.0

I am trying to edit a firebase object from a collection in a paper-dialog.

I am accessing the object in the on-click function of the button for the dialog with e.model. But how can I write back to it from within the Dialog?

```
<firebase-collection id="fbAccounts"
                location="https://xxx.firebaseio.com/accounts"
                data="{{accounts}}">
</firebase-collection>
```

The button to open the dialog:

```
<paper-icon-button icon="editor:mode-edit" on-click="openEditDialog"></paper-icon-button>
```

The Dialog:

```
<paper-dialog id="editContact">
  <h2>Edit Account</h2>
  <paper-input id="companyname" label="Company Name" value="{{data.accounts.name}}"></paper-input>
  <paper-input id="street" label="Street" value="{{data.accounts.street}}"></paper-input>
  <div class="horizontal layout">
    <paper-input id="postalcode" label="Postal Code" size="8" value="{{data.accounts.postalcode}}"></paper-input>
    <paper-input id="city" style="padding-left: 12px" label="City" value="{{data.accounts.city}}"></paper-input>
  </div>
  <paper-input id="country" label="Country" value="{{data.accounts.country}}"></paper-input>
  <div class="buttons">
    <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
    <paper-button dialog-confirm on-click="saveEditAccount">Save</paper-button>
  </div>
</paper-dialog>
```

And the scripts:

```
Polymer({

  is: 'accounts-view',
  properties: {
    data: {
      type: Object,
      notify: true
    }
  },

  openEditDialog: function(e) {
    this.data = e.model;
    this.$.editContact.open();
  },
  deleteAccount: function(e) {
    this.$.fbAccounts.remove(this.data.accounts);
  },
  saveEditAccount: function() {
    var account = this.$.fbAccounts.getByKey(this.data.accounts.__firebaseKey__);
    console.log(account);
  });
  }

});
```

Comment: Please provide some code snippets, easier to help you that way. :)

Comment: Thanks for providing code, but how are you "choosing" which account to edit? I see no where in the code where you "select" an actual account

Comment: in the openEditDialog I am having the e.model object which I store in data.

Comment: @JoergHerbarth did you make it work?
I am using a dom-repeat to show the items, and then a dialog to edit. The get edited live in the array, but not get updated in firebase